# Clear selected option in IE with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Imagine this HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clear_form() {
  $("select#block_id").find("option").removeAttr("selected");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select id="block_id" name="block_id">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">1 Peach Road</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">Bethnal Green Estate</option>
<option value="3">Ley Street</option>
<option value="4">Ogilby Street</option>
</select>
<input type="reset" onclick="clear_form()" value="Clear"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

When you open this page in Firefox pressing a Clear button will reset selected option.
But this doesn't work in IE, browser will not raise any errors but do nothing selected option still shown.
Problem is because we have 'option value="2" selected="selected"' html code and looks like IE won't clear this selection it always appear on page.
It will be great to get native javascript or jQuery 1.5.2 solution.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

You could use JavaScript to reset the `select` to point to its first `option` element.

With jQuery...

```
$('#block_id').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
```

Without...

```
document.getElementById('block_id').selectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: It will be great, but this doesn't works. In FF and Chrome this broke all clearing also in IE this still not helps. I focused question on me html code because i have option with 'selected="selected"' html code loaded to browser, your code will reset drop down list to same option with value=2 only if i load page and manually change selected option to other one.

Comment: @SergiyVolkov Please think of what the term *doesn't work* means to someone who can't see your screen. What doesn't work? Is there an error? Can you explain it better? The *doesn't work* rarely helps anyone...

Comment: 'doesn't works' means user who load this page will not see drop down list with no selected option when he press Clear button, i've just stuck on this IE related problem, because in FF and Chrome this works! :)

Comment: @SergiyVolkov I believe they will see no option as the first `option` child has no text node, which is rendering as an empty `select` element initially.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Reset button is reason why it is restoring the value in IE.

> A reset button resets all form fields to their initial values

In your case option 2 was initially selected and so the value is retained.

1. Change the button type to button instead of reset
2. Change the clear function as in Alex post.

   ```
   document.getElementById('block_id').selectedIndex = 0;
   ```

Comment: Great! problem was with input type="reset" i've change it to type="button" and my JS script clears drop down list. Thanks!